# How access network tab requests/response in console tab of browser

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, browser, console

My use case involves scrolling through posts of a facebook groups and then select some specific posts with some specific keywords and then write these posts' details into an excel sheet.

To do this I used to follow below steps

1. Open the network tab to start recording network traces
2. Run a script to keep scrolling the fb page
3. Download the HAR file
4. Use python to process the HAR file

However, this is a tedious process and runs into some memory issues as we keep scrolling for longer. I want to automate some of it and keep clearing the memory.

So the plan is to have just one script in JS which I'll paste in the console and then get the excel sheet.
Here is the updated script in JS

1. Open the network tab to start recording network traces
2. Run a script to keep scrolling the fb page
3. Access the network tab requests/response
4. Process them in JS only
5. Output to a local file.

Now I don't know if step 3 and 5 in updated script is possible or not. Can someone please guide?